# htaccess mod url re-writing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rebuilding an old website and have a bunch of old url's that I am having issues re-writing properly.

For example, some of my old URLs are structured as the following:

```
mydomain.com/?x=about-us **and** mydomain.com/?x=services
```

I would like the examples to rewrite or redirect to the following:

```
mydomain.com/about-us **and** mydomain.com/services
```

Essentially, if there is an occurrence of '?x=' in the URL I would like to strip it out.

Currently the only other cond/rule I have in .htaccess is to remove the '.php'. extensions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works well enough, and allows me to write my internal links without the '.php' extension, such as the following:

```
<a href="about-us">link</a>
```

This sends me to 'mydomain.com/about-us', which is what I want. My issue is handling URLs with the '?x='

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?x=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this didn't seem to work. Now all my links are sending me to the root directory for all of my localhost projects.

Comment: I edited my question a bit, maybe it's a little more clear now perhaps?

Comment: Try my updated rules and test. What happens when you enter URL as `mydomain.com/?x=about-us` in browser? Make sure you don't have any other rule and no other .htaccess

Comment: Hi, this works well for when the links are being hit from external sources (like other websites) or when entering the url manually into the browser. For the most part, this should do the trick. I will accept answer. Thanks.